# Jquery Collapse panel not working right behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am writing jquery for collapse panel.Expected behavior is not correct.

Current behavior : when i click any row its getting expand but not getting collapsed .

expected behavior : when i click one row should expand when i click another row similarly other row should open previous should get collapsed.
     Below is the code :

```
 **HTML**
<table id="paddin-sm" class=" fold-table  container table table-striped table-hover table-fw-widget dataTable no-footer">
                                                          <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <th>ID <span class="01"> </span></th>
                                                              <th>Name <span class="img-down-sy"> </span></th>
                                                              <th>Created By <span class="img-down-sy"> </span></th>
                                                              <th>Created Date <span class="img-down-sy"> </span></th>                          
                                                              <th>Type <span class="img-down-sy"> </span></th>
                                                              <th>Status <span class="img-down-sy"> </span></th>
                                                              <th>Actions </th>
                                                              <th>-</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </thead>
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr class="view">
                                                              <td>PID0006</td>
                                                              <td class="pcs">Robo Motors</td>
                                                              <td class="cur">Jordan Smith</td>
                                                              <td>20/27/2017</td>
                                                              <td class="per">SDLC</td>
                                                              <td class="per padding-left-27px"><span class="indicator-inprogress"></span>Open</td>
                                                              <td class="per ">
                                                                <div class="tools dropdown padding-left-15px">



                                                                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                                                                    data-toggle="dropdown"><span
                                                                      class="mdi mdi-more font-weight-b them-txt-color"></span></a>


                                                                  <div  class="posi-left dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right position-ee" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                      href="#">Edit</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Breakdown</a><a
                                                                      class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estimate</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add Actuals</a>
                                                                  </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                              </td>

                                                              <td><span class="chever-down mdi mdi-chevron-down"></span></td>

                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr class="fold">
                                                              <td colspan="10">
                                                                <div class="fold-content">
                                                                  <h3>Company Name</h3>
                                                                  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                                                                    egestas.</p>

                                                                </div>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr class="view">
                                                              <td>PID0005</td>
                                                              <td class="pcs">Robo Motors</td>
                                                              <td class="cur">Jordan Smith</td>
                                                              <td>20/27/2017</td>
                                                              <td class="per">SDLC</td>                
                                                              <td class="per padding-left-27px"><span class="indicator-done"></span>Close</td>
                                                              <td class="per">
                                                                <div class="tools dropdown padding-left-15px"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                                                                    data-toggle="dropdown"><span
                                                                      class="mdi mdi-more font-weight-b them-txt-color"></span></a>
                                                                  <div class="posi-left dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item"
                                                                      href="#">Edit</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Breakdown</a><a
                                                                      class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estimate</a>
                                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add Actuals</a>
                                                                  </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                              </td>

                                                              <td><span class="chever-down mdi mdi-chevron-down"></span></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr class="fold">
                                                              <td colspan="10">
                                                                <div class="fold-content">
                                                                  <h3>Company Name</h3>
                                                                  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis
                                                                    egestas.</p>

                                                                </div>
                                                              </td>
                                                            </tr>


                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".fold-table").find(".chever-down").on("click", function() {
var isSameTrOpen = false;
isSameTrOpen = $(this).closest("tr").next().hasClass('open');

            if (($("#paddin-sm").find(".open").length > 0) && !isSameTrOpen) {

                $("#paddin-sm").find(".open").removeClass("open").addClass("fold");
                $(this).closest("tr").next().hasClass('open').removeClass("mdi-chevron-up").addClass("mdi-chevron-down");
                $("#paddin-sm").find(".view").removeClass("table-row-clr");
            } else {
                $(this).closest("tr").find(".view").addClass("table-row-clr");
            }
           if ($(this).hasClass("mdi-chevron-down")) {
                $(this).removeClass("mdi-chevron-down").addClass("mdi-chevron-up");


                $(this).closest("tr").addClass("table-row-clr");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("mdi-chevron-up").addClass("mdi-chevron-down ");
                $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("table-row-clr");
            }
            $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").toggleClass("open ").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");

        })
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML please

Comment: Or, even better, create a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that reproduce the problem.

Comment: can any one have solution to help ?

Comment: Can you explain why you're setting isSameTrOpen to false, and then immediately mutating it into a jQuery object?